# TaskEx.WhenAll and Exceptions

Tags: .net-4.0, exception, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0, async-ctp

I'm constrained to using the .NET 4.0 framework and Async CTP Extensions to do something like the following:

```
     var dataTasks = _tasks.Select(t => t.GetData(keys));

     var results = TaskEx.WhenAll(dataTasks).Result.ToList();
```

where _tasks is a list of objects that each provide a GetData method that returns a `Task<Data>`.

My problem is that one of the `dataTasks` is throwing an exception and tanking the whole.  I'd like to be able to inspect the results of each dataTask and check the results, logging any exception and then continuing on with any valid results.  I'm unsure now to go about it though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a way of try-catching the WhenAll, and still get the remaining results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a trivial `ContinueWith()` to change a potentially faulting `Task<T>` into a successful `Task<Task<T>>`. If you then use `WhenAll().Result` on that (or `await WhenAll()`), you'll get `Task<T>[]`, which is exactly what you need:

```
var dataTasks = _tasks.Select(t => t.GetData(keys).ContinueWith(c => c));

Task<T>[] results = Task.WhenAll(dataTasks).Result;
```

Comment: Clever!  Thanks svick.  Works like a charm.

Comment: @John, you mean this permits "to inspect the results of each dataTask and check the results, logging any exception" also in case of an exception? I thought, but did not check, an exception is lost if one does not use `try/catch` around the line with `WhenAll()` call

Comment: @John, You can use `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll` in a similar fashion. This comes in handy if you are .NET 4.0 without Async CTP or Async targeting pack.

Comment: Is there a way to try catch the exception and still get the rest of the results?

Answer (score 0):

`TaskEx.WhenAll(dataTasks)` is your combined task. It might be faulted.

When calling `Result` this cause the exception to be thrown. So don't do that. Examine the `Exception` or `IsFaulted` properties.

Comment: But how to get to the results of successful `Task`s?

Comment: You keep track of the original list of tasks passed into `WhenAll`. When it returns you know that all of them have completed so you can reliably examine them.

Comment: Also, how do you find out when does the `Task` returned by `WhenAll()` complete? Because `Exception` or `IsFaulted` don't block.

Comment: If you're not ok with catching an Exception that `Wait` might throw you need to reimplement `WaitAll` or `WhenAll` which isn't too hard. Just hook up one continuation per task and keep track of how many completed with a synchronized counter. I wish there was better support for this built-in.